# CSS3 line-through style over text in slanted form?

Tags: css, styling

Is it possible in CSS3 to slant a strike-off line (achieved with css's *text-decoration: line-through* property) over a text string, say from bottom-left of the text to top-right (diagonal line)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know. What you could do if it isn't is put a div on top of it, color one of its borders and slant it.

Comment: I think `span` would be more suitable in this scenario.

Comment: You mean semantically? Maybe, but there will never be a 100% semantically correct of doing this since, well, it's a hack. Or did I misunderstand you? :\

Answer (score 0):

No - the line-through property is not intended for that and can't be used that way. It only adds Horizontal Lines to Characters / Strings. If You want to add an diagonal Line you would have to use maybe a layer over the Text with an PNG in it / as background Or Canvas.